# Why does Beamer not change the itemize symbol when using \setbeamertemplate?

Tags: beamer, itemize

This code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[square]


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item first level
    \begin{itemize}
    \item second level
        \begin{itemize}
        \item third level
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image: beamer output]

I expected the symbol of the first level item to be a circle, not a square. Is there an error in my code? The log file was too long to include in the question, so I [uploaded it to pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ZBAeJMFF).

Comment: I get a circle. Which version of beamer do you have? I tested with pdflatex from texlive 2018

Comment: Can you show your .log file?

Comment: @samcarter I'll add the log file to the question. I might have to add it as a link because it's longer than 30,000 characters. I'm actually not sure how to check what beamer version I have. I'm using the texlive distribution from the Debian stretch repo.

Comment: If the log is too long, you can upload it on https://pastebin.com/ (I will see your beamer version in the log file)

Comment: @samcarter Done. I added the link in the question.

Comment: This problem was fixed in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/8e1e4d838aa8e0cddd16239a7f63ae479999f671

Comment: This is a problem with xelatex and the old beamer version of your texlive. Can you by any chance update to texlive2018?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This had once been a problem with xelatex and beamer. The problem has been fixed in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/8e1e4d838aa8e0cddd16239a7f63ae479999f671

If you update texlive to the current texlive2018, the problem will be gone. If for whatever reason you cannot update, you could manually apply the fix:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\bullet$}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[square]


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item first level
    \begin{itemize}
    \item second level
        \begin{itemize}
        \item third level
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to update texlive/beamer manually, so I'm on the latest version now.